# Flatpickr monthyear plugin, up and down arrows don't update the view of the calendar

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flatpickr

I am using flatpickr monthYear plugin for date selection.
I've set min and max date also.
if i use the side arrows things work as expected year changes and also the view , but when i click on the up and down arrows to change year, year changes but not the view

here is the codesandbox for the issue.
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-fermi-xwqs50?file=/src/monthpicker.js